# Why does the source code, which Veil compiles and runs successfully, not work when I try to run it directly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, payload

When I obtain the payload output with Python in the Veil framework, the .exe file works successfully. However, when I copy the source code from the .py file to my computer and compile it, I encounter the error `'exception: access violation writing 0x00000000CCCF0000'.`

The relevant line is as follows:

```
m.windll.kernel32.RtlMoveMemory(b.c_int(e), s, m.c_int(len(z)))
```

I have tried many different methods, but there is no difference. What exactly does Veil do differently from what I'm doing?